# Which port is this?

Tags: lenovo-laptop

Cannot figure out what this port does. anyone has any idea? It is on lenovo y 40-80.

[image]

Comment: It's a [K-slot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the user manual it is for a cable lock (sold separately).
http://www.manualslib.com/manual/741692/Lenovo-Y40-70.html?page=18#manual